# error removenumber textmining

Tags: r, text-mining, corpus

I have imported a csv file that has about 40 columns and 2000 observations (rows) a mix of numbers and text to create a corpus.
I asked the following question here on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228717/text-mining-policy-documents) and got no responses. Hoping for some directions on approach + error fixing on the code so far

Intention is to use various text mining techniques to:

1. explore whatever that can be derived (of business value) out of this corpus containing one file - meaning I have no particular goal in mind since I'm not sure whether I'd gain anything out of this (more than likely I will)
2. I will as a second step, then import multiple csv files of the same format/structure i.e. the number of columns and the column headers will be the same only the number of rows will be different. I will then try to run some text mining analysis (basic to advanced) to see if there is anything that can be of value.

   ```
   myfile <- read.csv("myfile.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
   str(myfile) colnames(myfile) 

   myfile_comment <- paste(myfile$comment,collapse = " ")
   myfile_source  <- VectorSource(myfile_comment)
   corpus         <- Corpus(myfile_source)
   corpus         <- tm_map(corpus,PlainTextDocument) 
   corpus         <- tm_map(corpus,content_transformer(tolower)) 
   corpus         <- tm_map(corpus,removePunctuation) 
   corpus         <- tm_map(corpus,stripWhitespace) 
   corpus         <- tm_map(corpus,removeWords,stopwords("english")) 
   corpus         <- tm_filter(corpus,removeNumbers) 
   corpus         <- tm_map(corpus,stemDocument) 
   dtm            <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus) 
   dtm_n          <- as.matrix(dtm) 
   freq           <- colSums(dtm_n) 
   freq           <- sort(freq,decreasing = TRUE) 
   words          <- names(freq) 
   wordcloud(words[1:100],freq[1:100])
   ```

If I don't use `removeNumbers`, the wordcloud is generated. If I use `removeNumbers` code (in the order above), I get an error:

> Error in UseMethod("stemDocument", x) :  no applicable method for
>   'stemDocument' applied to an object of class "NULL"

EDIT:

`str(corpus)` generates:

```
List of 1
 $ character(0):List of 2
  ..$ content: chr " report   appropriate item fees  similar penalty applied associated   borrowing reportable  line item"| __truncated__
  ..$ meta   :List of 7
  .. ..$ author       : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ datetimestamp: POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2016-08-13 00:09:29"
  .. ..$ description  : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ heading      : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ id           : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ language     : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ origin       : chr(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "TextDocumentMeta"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "PlainTextDocument" "TextDocument"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "VCorpus" "Corpus"
```

Comment: updated description

Comment: You should probably use `tm_map` instead of `tm_filter` while removing numbers

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick. I'm also looking for some more directions (theoretical) to my overall intent. Please share insights.

Comment: You should rephrase your question on CV and ask there about the theoretical concepts.

Comment: We focus on errors in code here. For "general direction" this is not the right site. Try [stats.se] or [datascience.se]. Be much more specific about what your question is.

Comment: Agreed. I will add that its never ever a bad idea to read the cran task view for the subject. Look for packages and read vignettes. [link here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html).

Comment: I've actually read a few but what I'm unsure about is the implementation of steps. E.g. I read about lemmatization being better than stemming. There are vignettes/articles but none provides a conclusive result - they offer the code and isolated output